NetManager, systemd-networkd and Chrome
I have installed status system-networkd and configured this service.
My understanding is you either have system-networkd or NetManager but not both.
But since installing and removing NetManager I see the following in my syslogs.
2024-12-23T12:22:36.185786+13:00 oliver google-chrome.desktop[4491]: [4484:5196:1223/122236.185393:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(576)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.GetDevices:
Is there something I should be doing with Chrome to make this work without NetworkManager or do I need to stop using system-networkd?
Thanks

You dont need to disable systemd-network if your network work fine, your message is not unusual when using NetworkManager and it doesnt break chrome , you can ignore it since it is just a log, you can disable proxy auto-detection or system integration if it bother you still.

I have disabled NetworkManager in preference to system-networkd. I did this as the NeworkManager, on occasion, kept starting and stopping, maybe once or twice a day.
I looks like to me that Chrome depends on NetworkManager being or is spits out the  ERROR:object_proxy.cc(576)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.GetDevices
